# CoffeeScript on click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, coffeescript

I'm new to CoffeeScript and JS. I'm trying to create an alert when a div is clicked, but I'm not sure why my code isn't working. All of these files are in the same directory.

**first.coffee**

```
$('#button').on 'click', -> alert 'Hello World!'
```

I've tried this with and without the hash before `button`.

And after compiling this:

**first.js**

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.12.4
(function() {
  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    return alert('Hello World!');
  });

}).call(this);
```

And the HTML looks like this. I've tried moving the script to the header too but I don't think that makes a difference.

**first.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>CoffeeScript</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="first.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='button'></div>
        <script src='first.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the styling for the div:

**first.css**

```
#button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the jQuery javascript libraries before your script

```
<body>
    <div id='button'></div>
    <script src='/path/to/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'></script>
    <script src='first.js'></script>
</body>
```

You will need to download jQuery to your system and provide the correct path.